# connectify hotspot traffic can be identified in someway?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hotspot, connectify

in my company my chief sometimes when some guests come to office and have not wifi credentials, he asks us to share wifi with connectify on the fly.
But I'm concerned about security: (it's a large company, with large it and network infrastructure) for example, if someone with whom I share the connection, visit some sites or downloads something, or simply makes somethings he must not do, will be the network team be able to identify the correct responsible? or when sharing the connection with connectify or other hotspot tools, there's no way to identify the traffic and the person which shares the connection is the "responsible" of all the traffic?
I'm not an expert of networking

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: So there's no way to determine the real source of traffic?

Comment: - Please do not vandalize other people's answers.

Answer (score 1):

It'll look like it's originating from the device that serves the hotspot. You should really be using APs that allow you to set up a separate network for guest access, preferably with additional security features than your ordinary network, for example limiting traffic from the different computers on the network to the upstream gateway and not other clients on the same WiFi network.

Comment: Networking/security team, can do some analysis checking for example the ports of incoming outcoming connections?